# Display Templates vs. View Models for Simple Classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have 50+ basic data classes, and want to use a consistent approach to displaying these in 3 or 4 different formats.

I know that most experts recommend the use of `ViewModels`.  Some even [recommend one per view](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/).

But surely there would be less code to create / maintain by just using different `DisplayTemplates` directly on the data model.

For example, compare these 3 apporaches:

---

**1: No ViewModels, Use DisplayTemplates for Different Formats**

```
class Person
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string NickName {get;set;}
    public string Nationality {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteColour {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteBand {get;set;}
}

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Person, "Simple")

@Html.DisplayFor(m =>m.Person, "Full")
```

This appears to be the simplest option, with the least code to create and maintain.

---

**2: Use a ViewModel Only When Deviating from Data Model**

```
class Person
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string NickName {get;set;}
    public string Nationality {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteColour {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteBand {get;set;}
}

class PersonSimpleViewModel
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string NickName {get;set;}
    public string Nationality {get;set;}
}

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Person)

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PersonSimpleViewModel)
```

This would require an additional VM for every entity, and the use / configuration of a system like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ExpressMapper](http://www.expressmapper.org/).

I feel like it's unnecessarily adding complexity. Also, x by 50 entities and it's lot more code to create / maintain.

---

**3:  A View Model for Every Display Format**

```
class Person
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string NickName {get;set;}
    public string Nationality {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteColour {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteBand {get;set;}
}

class PersonSimpleViewModel
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string NickName {get;set;}
    public string Nationality {get;set;}
}

class PersonFullViewModel
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string NickName {get;set;}
    public string Nationality {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteColour {get;set;}
    public string FavouriteBand {get;set;}
}

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PersonSimpleViewModel)

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PersonFullViewModel)
```

This option requires the most code, and it feels silly because the `Full` VM is identical to the data model.

However I would prefer this over 2 because it is consistent - every display format has it's corresponding VM and the data model is nowhere in sight.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing any more specifics about your application or its requirements, it's hard to say whether you should be creating viewmodels or not. One option you have is to avoid them and use your entity classes until you realize you need viewmodels.

> ...x by 50 entities and it's lot more code to create / maintain.

Not sure I buy this argument. It would probably take you only a couple of minutes at most to create each viewmodel class. Say it takes 5 minutes to create each viewmodel, and another 5 minutes to wire it up to either Automapper or ExpressMapper. That's 10 minutes for each entity. If you took a 10 minute break every hour, you could get 5 of these done each hour, which means 10 hours to do them all. That's a little more than a day's work (that you should probably *not* do all at once, but piecemeal as needed).

Also keep in mind that in reality you probably won't need to create a viewmodel per entity, you will want to create a viewmodel *per view*. Often the data you want to present to a user is a join of 2 or more entities in tandem. If you need these viewmodels for data entry, then the join argument may not apply, but others do. For example, what if you want to apply an attribute to a viewmodel so that you can apply serialization or validation rules to it. You wouldn't want to add these attributes on an entity class because it is responsible for data storage, not user input serialization or validation.

Then there are derived properties. Say for one of your views, you wanted to have a `DisplayName` property for your `Person`. Would you add something like the following to your entity?

```
public string DisplayName => $"{FirstName} ({NickName}) {LastName}";
```

Why pollute the data storage class with something you only need when presenting the data to a user?

> I feel like it's unnecessarily adding complexity.

It may be, which is why I said this is a hard question to answer without knowing a lot more details about your application. These viewmodels are really just "data buckets" to me, so I really don't see them as complex. That said, there is an additional cost to maintaining this separation. Like anything, whether or not that cost is justified depends on what desirable benefits you are able to get out of it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to create a **consistent infrastructure** that I can follow when creating apps.  So on one hand I want to keep it flexibile and 'best practice'. On the other hand I don't want to tie myself to creating a million VMs (slight exaggeration)  for every entity I add.

Comment: In this case I am talking about simple, common entities only - e.g. social profile URLs, contact form recipients, page tags.  Larger / complex entities will likely be customised per app.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some general guidance.

Use the entity when it's display only. The biggest problem with passing entities to the view is when you're allowing that entity to be modified in some way. If it's just data being displayed as read only, by all means use the entity and don't worry about extra classes.

Use a view model when you're accepting user input. You want the extra step of mapping from the view model to the entity to allow you clean up user input as necessary, and you can then only allow the properties that should be allowed to be modified to be modified.

Short of that, use a view model when makes sense to. If there's some sort of complex processing that you need to do on certain properties in order to display them, then a view model is a great place for that logic. Or, you can use a view model to make property access easier. Basically, use a view model, when doing so allows you to reduce the amount of logic that needs to go in the view. Your view should have as little logic as possible, and a view model can often help with that.